# mean.io installation on windows

Tags: node.js, mean.io

I followed the steps as specified at http://learn.mean.io/.
I ran cmd as an adiminstrator.
But i'm getting below error on running but getting below error:

```
On windows platform - Please check permissions independently
All permissions should be run with the local users permissions
Cloning branch: master into destination folder: myApp2
git clone  --depth 1  -bmaster https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git "myApp2"
FIND: Parameter format not correct
There are 2 files in your ~/.npm owned by root
Please change the permissions by running - chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
C:\Users\CE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\lib\utils.js:67
      throw('ROOT PERMISSIONS IN NPM');
      ^
ROOT PERMISSIONS IN NPM
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\lib\` you will see at the line `59` something like this:

```
exports.checkNpmPermission = function (callback){
  var homeDir = process.env[isWin ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'];
  var findCmd = 'find ' + homeDir +'/.npm ' + '-user root';
  shell.exec(findCmd, function( status, output){
    var hasRootFiles = output.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;
    if (hasRootFiles > 1){
      console.log (chalk.red('There are ' + hasRootFiles + ' files in your ~/.npm owned by root'));
      console.log(chalk.green('Please change the permissions by running -'), 'chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm ');
      throw('ROOT PERMISSIONS IN NPM');
    }
  });
  callback();
};
```

The command: `var findCmd = 'find ' + homeDir +'/.npm ' + '-user root';` will not work on windows. Try to remove whole `shell.exec(...)` segment for workaround on your windows machine and then try to `init` your mean app again.

Hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Annoying to have to edit the mean-cli source just to get a new project started.

Comment: I created a fork that removes the offensive code. Use: `npm install -g git://github.com/djskinner/mean-cli.git`